# Github API get the link header with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, github-api

I'm using github api for a small web app and at some point I need to get [link header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/9707-link-header.html) for [the pagination](http://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination).

The final goal is to get the total number of commits per repository, I found that [python script](https://gist.github.com/1241096) and tried to adapt it to JavaScript.

```
getData = $.getJSON('https://api.github.com/repos/'+user+'/'+repo+'/commits?callback=?', function (commits){

    console.log(getData.getResponseHeader('link'))
    // will return null

    console.log(getData.getAllResponseHeaders('link'))
    // will return an empty string

    console.log(commits)
    // will successfuly return my json
});
```

`user` and `repo` are respectively the user name and his repo name

It's for a Github page so I can only use JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the GitHub API docs for using JSONP callbacks: http://developer.github.com/v3/#json-p-callbacks

Basically, if you're using JSONP to call the API, then you won't get a `Link` header, but you will instead get the same information in the response JSON document (i.e. the body). Below is the example from the API docs, notice the `Link` property in the `meta` object

```
$ curl https://api.github.com?callback=foo

foo({
  "meta": {
    "status": 200,
    "X-RateLimit-Limit": "5000",
    "X-RateLimit-Remaining": "4966",
    "Link": [ // pagination headers and other links
      ["https://api.github.com?page=2", {"rel": "next"}]
    ]
  },
  "data": {
    // the data
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature for the function you pass to the [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method is 
    Type: Function( PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )

To access the Link header you should use the jqXHR object instead of the data object:

```
getData = $.getJSON(
     'https://api.github.com/repos/'+user+'/'+repo+'/commits?callback=?',
     function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){

        console.log(jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Link'))
        // will return the Header Link

        console.log(commits)
        // will successfuly return my json
    });
```